# Who will leave a blessing behind and for whom in Joel 2:14?

Tags: referent-identification, joel

Joel 2:14 ESV

***Who knows whether he will not turn and relent,
and leave a blessing behind him,
a grain offering and a drink offering
for the Lord your God?***

Its not clear in the above text who leaves a blessing behind and for whom?

Answer (score 2):

The antecedent of the pronouns in Joel 2:14 is the LORD in V13.

The problem here is the overly succinct Hebrew language that leaves a word or two implied.  The most helpful and conservative translation is perhaps the NASB which reads:

> Who knows, He might turn and relent, And leave a blessing behind Him,
> *Resulting in* a grain offering and a drink offering For the LORD your God.

Notice that the translators have had to supply a verb "resulting in" to correctly render the right sense of the Hebrew.  This is supported by several other versions such as the CEV, etc.

Note the comments of Ellicott -

> (14) **Even a meat offering**.—The returning favour of the Lord will
> enable the daily sacrifices to be restored, which had failed through
> the visitation (Joel 1:9).

The Cambridge commentary is similar -

> **and leave a blessing behind him** as he turns back.
>
> **a blessing** viz. by permitting the earth again to mature its fruits and yield materials for the meal-and drink-offerings in the sanctuary
> (Joel 1:9).

**Another View**

If we insist on reading the Hebrew literally without the supplied verb as above, then we might understand that God is so gracious that when He relents of His fierce judgement, among the blessings he leaves behind is the thank-you gift (as required by Torah rules) to be given at the temple.